# Spring Security access denied on custom security

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-security

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class SecurityConfig {

    private final UserService userService;
    private final PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder;

    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain filterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

        http.csrf().disable()
                .sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS)
                .and().authorizeHttpRequests(authorize -> authorize.requestMatchers("/api/v1/user/login", "/api/v1/user/register")
                .permitAll()
                .anyRequest().authenticated());
        http.cors();

        CustomFilter customFilter = new CustomFilter(authenticationManager(http.getSharedObject(AuthenticationConfiguration.class)));
        customFilter.setSecurityContextRepository(new DelegatingSecurityContextRepository(
                new RequestAttributeSecurityContextRepository(),
                new HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository()
        ));
        http.addFilterAt(customFilter, UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);

        return http.build();
    }

    @Bean
    public AuthenticationManager authenticationManager(AuthenticationConfiguration authenticationConfiguration) throws Exception {
        DaoAuthenticationProvider authProvider = new DaoAuthenticationProvider();
        authProvider.setUserDetailsService(userService);
        authProvider.setPasswordEncoder(passwordEncoder);
        return new ProviderManager(authProvider);
    }
}
```

```
@Slf4j
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class CustomFilter extends UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter {

    private final AuthenticationManager authenticationManager;

    @Override
    public Authentication attemptAuthentication(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws AuthenticationException {
        log.info("in filter");
        log.info("username is {} password is", request.getParameter("username"), request.getParameter("password"));
        return authenticationManager.authenticate(new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken("test", "test123"));
    }
}
```

Keep getting access denied on /api/v1/user/login request however for /api/v1/user/register seems to work.

```
2023-04-16T20:21:09.844+01:00 TRACE 7264 --- [nio-8080-exec-5] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Trying to match request against DefaultSecurityFilterChain [RequestMatcher=any request, Filters=[org.springframework.security.web.session.DisableEncodeUrlFilter@78324e97, org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter@73417494, org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextHolderFilter@b75f3f4, org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter@4e481512, org.springframework.web.filter.CorsFilter@29b0c169, org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter@4c6eaa65, com.example.language.security.CustomFilter@4d1b4fa1, org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter@5570dc21, org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter@583b4af4, org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter@27b7e663, org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter@4b552b13, org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter@1bcf2c64, org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.AuthorizationFilter@22ea6051]] (1/1)
2023-04-16T20:21:09.844+01:00 DEBUG 7264 --- [nio-8080-exec-5] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Securing POST /api/v1/user/login
2023-04-16T20:21:09.844+01:00 TRACE 7264 --- [nio-8080-exec-5] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Invoking DisableEncodeUrlFilter (1/13)
2023-04-16T20:21:09.844+01:00 TRACE 7264 --- [nio-8080-exec-5] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Invoking WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter (2/13)
2023-04-16T20:21:09.844+01:00 TRACE 7264 --- [nio-8080-exec-5] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Invoking SecurityContextHolderFilter (3/13)
2023-04-16T20:21:09.845+01:00 TRACE 7264 --- [nio-8080-exec-5] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Invoking HeaderWriterFilter (4/13)
2023-04-16T20:21:09.845+01:00 TRACE 7264 --- [nio-8080-exec-5] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Invoking CorsFilter (5/13)
2023-04-16T20:21:09.845+01:00 TRACE 7264 --- [nio-8080-exec-5] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Invoking LogoutFilter (6/13)
2023-04-16T20:21:09.845+01:00 TRACE 7264 --- [nio-8080-exec-5] o.s.s.w.a.logout.LogoutFilter            : Did not match request to Or [Ant [pattern='/logout', GET], Ant [pattern='/logout', POST], Ant [pattern='/logout', PUT], Ant [pattern='/logout', DELETE]]
2023-04-16T20:21:09.845+01:00 TRACE 7264 --- [nio-8080-exec-5] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Invoking CustomFilter (7/13)
2023-04-16T20:21:09.845+01:00 TRACE 7264 --- [nio-8080-exec-5] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Invoking RequestCacheAwareFilter (8/13)
2023-04-16T20:21:09.845+01:00 TRACE 7264 --- [nio-8080-exec-5] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Invoking SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter (9/13)
2023-04-16T20:21:09.845+01:00 TRACE 7264 --- [nio-8080-exec-5] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Invoking AnonymousAuthenticationFilter (10/13)
2023-04-16T20:21:09.845+01:00 TRACE 7264 --- [nio-8080-exec-5] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Invoking SessionManagementFilter (11/13)
2023-04-16T20:21:09.845+01:00 TRACE 7264 --- [nio-8080-exec-5] .s.s.w.c.SupplierDeferredSecurityContext : Created SecurityContextImpl [Null authentication]
2023-04-16T20:21:09.845+01:00 TRACE 7264 --- [nio-8080-exec-5] o.s.s.w.a.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter  : Set SecurityContextHolder to AnonymousAuthenticationToken [Principal=anonymousUser, Credentials=[PROTECTED], Authenticated=true, Details=WebAuthenticationDetails [RemoteIpAddress=0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1, SessionId=null], Granted Authorities=[ROLE_ANONYMOUS]]
2023-04-16T20:21:09.845+01:00 DEBUG 7264 --- [nio-8080-exec-5] o.s.s.w.session.SessionManagementFilter  : Request requested invalid session id AB69A2797C628E2B4090EB5B9DAEB1D0
2023-04-16T20:21:09.846+01:00 TRACE 7264 --- [nio-8080-exec-5] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Invoking ExceptionTranslationFilter (12/13)
2023-04-16T20:21:09.846+01:00 TRACE 7264 --- [nio-8080-exec-5] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Invoking AuthorizationFilter (13/13)
2023-04-16T20:21:09.846+01:00 TRACE 7264 --- [nio-8080-exec-5] estMatcherDelegatingAuthorizationManager : Authorizing SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestWrapper[ org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter$HeaderWriterRequest@64e3a996]
2023-04-16T20:21:09.846+01:00 TRACE 7264 --- [nio-8080-exec-5] estMatcherDelegatingAuthorizationManager : Checking authorization on SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestWrapper[ org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter$HeaderWriterRequest@64e3a996] using org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configurers.AuthorizeHttpRequestsConfigurer$$Lambda$1339/0x0000000801355380@45bc80c6
2023-04-16T20:21:09.846+01:00 DEBUG 7264 --- [nio-8080-exec-5] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Secured POST /api/v1/user/login
2023-04-16T20:21:09.848+01:00 TRACE 7264 --- [nio-8080-exec-5] o.s.s.w.header.writers.HstsHeaderWriter  : Not injecting HSTS header since it did not match request to [Is Secure]
2023-04-16T20:21:09.849+01:00 TRACE 7264 --- [nio-8080-exec-5] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Trying to match request against DefaultSecurityFilterChain [RequestMatcher=any request, Filters=[org.springframework.security.web.session.DisableEncodeUrlFilter@78324e97, org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter@73417494, org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextHolderFilter@b75f3f4, org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter@4e481512, org.springframework.web.filter.CorsFilter@29b0c169, org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter@4c6eaa65, com.example.language.security.CustomFilter@4d1b4fa1, org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter@5570dc21, org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter@583b4af4, org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter@27b7e663, org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter@4b552b13, org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter@1bcf2c64, org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.AuthorizationFilter@22ea6051]] (1/1)
2023-04-16T20:21:09.849+01:00 DEBUG 7264 --- [nio-8080-exec-5] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Securing POST /error
2023-04-16T20:21:09.849+01:00 TRACE 7264 --- [nio-8080-exec-5] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Invoking DisableEncodeUrlFilter (1/13)
2023-04-16T20:21:09.849+01:00 TRACE 7264 --- [nio-8080-exec-5] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Invoking WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter (2/13)
2023-04-16T20:21:09.849+01:00 TRACE 7264 --- [nio-8080-exec-5] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Invoking SecurityContextHolderFilter (3/13)
2023-04-16T20:21:09.849+01:00 TRACE 7264 --- [nio-8080-exec-5] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Invoking HeaderWriterFilter (4/13)
2023-04-16T20:21:09.850+01:00 TRACE 7264 --- [nio-8080-exec-5] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Invoking CorsFilter (5/13)
2023-04-16T20:21:09.850+01:00 TRACE 7264 --- [nio-8080-exec-5] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Invoking LogoutFilter (6/13)
2023-04-16T20:21:09.850+01:00 TRACE 7264 --- [nio-8080-exec-5] o.s.s.w.a.logout.LogoutFilter            : Did not match request to Or [Ant [pattern='/logout', GET], Ant [pattern='/logout', POST], Ant [pattern='/logout', PUT], Ant [pattern='/logout', DELETE]]
2023-04-16T20:21:09.850+01:00 TRACE 7264 --- [nio-8080-exec-5] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Invoking CustomFilter (7/13)
2023-04-16T20:21:09.850+01:00 TRACE 7264 --- [nio-8080-exec-5] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Invoking RequestCacheAwareFilter (8/13)
2023-04-16T20:21:09.850+01:00 TRACE 7264 --- [nio-8080-exec-5] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Invoking SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter (9/13)
2023-04-16T20:21:09.850+01:00 TRACE 7264 --- [nio-8080-exec-5] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Invoking AnonymousAuthenticationFilter (10/13)
2023-04-16T20:21:09.850+01:00 TRACE 7264 --- [nio-8080-exec-5] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Invoking SessionManagementFilter (11/13)
2023-04-16T20:21:09.850+01:00 TRACE 7264 --- [nio-8080-exec-5] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Invoking ExceptionTranslationFilter (12/13)
2023-04-16T20:21:09.850+01:00 TRACE 7264 --- [nio-8080-exec-5] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Invoking AuthorizationFilter (13/13)
2023-04-16T20:21:09.850+01:00 TRACE 7264 --- [nio-8080-exec-5] estMatcherDelegatingAuthorizationManager : Authorizing SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestWrapper[ FirewalledRequest[ org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationHttpRequest@4b36ae0e]]
2023-04-16T20:21:09.851+01:00 TRACE 7264 --- [nio-8080-exec-5] estMatcherDelegatingAuthorizationManager : Checking authorization on SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestWrapper[ FirewalledRequest[ org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationHttpRequest@4b36ae0e]] using org.springframework.security.authorization.AuthenticatedAuthorizationManager@59fb0a7f
2023-04-16T20:21:09.851+01:00 TRACE 7264 --- [nio-8080-exec-5] .s.s.w.c.SupplierDeferredSecurityContext : Created SecurityContextImpl [Null authentication]
2023-04-16T20:21:09.851+01:00 TRACE 7264 --- [nio-8080-exec-5] o.s.s.w.a.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter  : Set SecurityContextHolder to AnonymousAuthenticationToken [Principal=anonymousUser, Credentials=[PROTECTED], Authenticated=true, Details=WebAuthenticationDetails [RemoteIpAddress=0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1, SessionId=null], Granted Authorities=[ROLE_ANONYMOUS]]
2023-04-16T20:21:09.851+01:00 TRACE 7264 --- [nio-8080-exec-5] o.s.s.w.a.ExceptionTranslationFilter     : Sending AnonymousAuthenticationToken [Principal=anonymousUser, Credentials=[PROTECTED], Authenticated=true, Details=WebAuthenticationDetails [RemoteIpAddress=0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1, SessionId=null], Granted Authorities=[ROLE_ANONYMOUS]] to authentication entry point since access is denied

org.springframework.security.access.AccessDeniedException: Access Denied
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.AuthorizationFilter.doFilter(AuthorizationFilter.java:98) ~[spring-security-web-6.0.2.jar:6.0.2]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:374) ~[spring-security-web-6.0.2.jar:6.0.2]
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:126) ~[spring-security-web-6.0.2.jar:6.0.2]
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:120) ~[spring-security-web-6.0.2.jar:6.0.2]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:374) ~[spring-security-web-6.0.2.jar:6.0.2]
    at org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:91) ~[spring-security-web-6.0.2.jar:6.0.2]
    at org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:85) ~[spring-security-web-6.0.2.jar:6.0.2]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:374) ~[spring-security-web-6.0.2.jar:6.0.2]
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:100) ~[spring-security-web-6.0.2.jar:6.0.2]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:374) ~[spring-security-web-6.0.2.jar:6.0.2]
    at org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:179) ~[spring-security-web-6.0.2.jar:6.0.2]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:374) ~[spring-security-web-6.0.2.jar:6.0.2]
    at org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:63) ~[spring-security-web-6.0.2.jar:6.0.2]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:374) ~[spring-security-web-6.0.2.jar:6.0.2]
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:227) ~[spring-security-web-6.0.2.jar:6.0.2]
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:221) ~[spring-security-web-6.0.2.jar:6.0.2]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:374) ~[spring-security-web-6.0.2.jar:6.0.2]
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:107) ~[spring-security-web-6.0.2.jar:6.0.2]
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:93) ~[spring-security-web-6.0.2.jar:6.0.2]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:374) ~[spring-security-web-6.0.2.jar:6.0.2]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:101) ~[spring-web-6.0.7.jar:6.0.7]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:374) ~[spring-security-web-6.0.2.jar:6.0.2]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:101) ~[spring-web-6.0.7.jar:6.0.7]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:374) ~[spring-security-web-6.0.2.jar:6.0.2]
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextHolderFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderFilter.java:82) ~[spring-security-web-6.0.2.jar:6.0.2]
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextHolderFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderFilter.java:69) ~[spring-security-web-6.0.2.jar:6.0.2]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:374) ~[spring-security-web-6.0.2.jar:6.0.2]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:101) ~[spring-web-6.0.7.jar:6.0.7]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:374) ~[spring-security-web-6.0.2.jar:6.0.2]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:101) ~[spring-web-6.0.7.jar:6.0.7]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:374) ~[spring-security-web-6.0.2.jar:6.0.2]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:233) ~[spring-security-web-6.0.2.jar:6.0.2]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:191) ~[spring-security-web-6.0.2.jar:6.0.2]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:352) ~[spring-web-6.0.7.jar:6.0.7]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:268) ~[spring-web-6.0.7.jar:6.0.7]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:174) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.7.jar:10.1.7]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:149) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.7.jar:10.1.7]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:100) ~[spring-web-6.0.7.jar:6.0.7]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116) ~[spring-web-6.0.7.jar:6.0.7]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:174) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.7.jar:10.1.7]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:149) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.7.jar:10.1.7]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:101) ~[spring-web-6.0.7.jar:6.0.7]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:174) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.7.jar:10.1.7]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:149) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.7.jar:10.1.7]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:101) ~[spring-web-6.0.7.jar:6.0.7]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:174) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.7.jar:10.1.7]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:149) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.7.jar:10.1.7]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:642) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.7.jar:10.1.7]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.processRequest(ApplicationDispatcher.java:410) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.7.jar:10.1.7]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doForward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:340) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.7.jar:10.1.7]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.forward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:277) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.7.jar:10.1.7]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.custom(StandardHostValve.java:358) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.7.jar:10.1.7]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.status(StandardHostValve.java:222) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.7.jar:10.1.7]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:151) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.7.jar:10.1.7]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:93) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.7.jar:10.1.7]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:74) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.7.jar:10.1.7]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:341) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.7.jar:10.1.7]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:390) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.7.jar:10.1.7]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:63) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.7.jar:10.1.7]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:894) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.7.jar:10.1.7]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1741) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.7.jar:10.1.7]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:52) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.7.jar:10.1.7]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1191) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.7.jar:10.1.7]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:659) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.7.jar:10.1.7]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.7.jar:10.1.7]
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833) ~[na:na]

2023-04-16T20:21:09.851+01:00 DEBUG 7264 --- [nio-8080-exec-5] o.s.s.w.a.Http403ForbiddenEntryPoint     : Pre-authenticated entry point called. Rejecting access
```

I've tried debugging but it doesn't even seem to hit my custom filter but in the logs it is show that it is. Also attached the logs. I just can't seem to figure out why it would give an access denied even though i've permitted the url for all and seeing as one I'm a bit confused.

Comment: `UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter` is only applied for URL `/login` not for `/api/v1/user/login`.